# Exactly solvable quantum dynamics problems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution, integrable-systems

By exactly solvable model, people generally mean models whose eigenstates or eigenenergies can be solved analytically. Simple examples are the harmonic oscillator, the infinitely deep square well potential, the hydrogen atom, the Bethe ansatz solvable models (like the 1d Heisenberg model), etc.

However, for many such models, e.g., the Bethe ansatz solvable models, the solvability cannot be generalized to the time domain.

So, is there any example whose dynamics can also be solved exactly? I know the harmonic oscillator is one. Is there any extra nontrivial model?

ps: The [Landau-Zener problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Zener_formula) is also one, of course.

Comment: This post (v1) seems like a list question. See also this related [Wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum-mechanical_systems_with_analytical_solutions).

Comment: Actually there is a pretty long list of such problems and this site is probably not the appropriate place to ask for it.

Comment: @Qmechanic unfortunately, that Wikipedia list isn't all that reliable, cf. e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266216/are-there-exact-analytical-solutions-to-the-electronic-states-of-the-hydrogen-mo).

Comment: @Qmechanic  I am not asking for models whose eigenstates can be solved. I am asking for models whose dynamics can be solved. The latter is much rare than the former.