# Why does the hydrogen molecular ion has no bound state except the bonding state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hydrogen, molecules

Using LCAO method, we can determine the ground state of the hydrogen molecular ion. It is the spatially symmetric state given by $$\psi_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\psi_{1s}(r_A)+\psi_{1s}(r_B)\right]$$ where $r_A,r_B$ are the distances of the electron from the nuclei A and B. This is called the bonding state. It turns out that the spatially antisymmetric state given by $$\psi_-=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\psi_{1s}(r_A)-\psi_{1s}(r_B)\right]$$ has positive energy. Therefore, I think, the H-molecular ion in this state is not a bound system. In this state, the hydrogen molecular ion is disintegrated. If so, then H molecular ion has only one bound state - the bonding state.

Why is this the case? I mean, H-atom has many bound states. But H molecular ion has only one bound state. Why is this so?

Comment: are you not confusing molecular bond in $H_2$ with electronic state in hydrogen atom? These are apples and oranges.

Comment: @RogerVadim Both the H-atom and the H-molecular ion are one-electron systems, and in each case, we are looking for electron energies. Isn't it?

Comment: @Solidification Vadim's question is pertinent. $\text{H}_2^+$ is unstable because one electron cannot provide enough shielding  between the $+$ nuclei.

Comment: @Gert Do you have a reference that says that $H_2^+$ is unstable? In fact, the textbook by Bransden and Joachain (Physics of Atoms and Molecules) solves the $H_2^+$ problem and determines the ground state and ground-state energy. It turns out that one electron alone is capable of binding the system.

Comment: Being able to calculate the ground state has little to do with stability. If the molecular hydrogen ion was stable, salts of it would exist, like $\text{H}_2^+\text{Cl}^-$ e.g.

Comment: Relevant: [Dihydrogen cation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrogen_cation), [Are there exact analytical solutions to the electronic states of the hydrogen molecular ion H+2
?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266216/247642)

Comment: Googling suggests there are at least two excited states of H₂⁺ that are bound i.e. a P and D state as well as the S ground state. If you mix only the 1s atomic orbitals obviously you will get only two states - the bonding and antibonding MOs. To find the other states you need to include the other atomic orbitals.